# Ruby/Regex: Dealing with strings containing forward slashes and parentheses using gsub and regex

Tags: ruby, regex, watir, watir-webdriver, gsub

Hi I am using Watir to click through some links. I go to a page, click a link based on its text, and the do it again click a new link. I am locating the links based on their text (it is the only way I can based on their HTML) and need to match the text I pulled from the page to the link. The text that I get contains some extra text not part of the link, so I need to gsub it out. Here is my issue:

String: `text = "Nuclear Launch Codes (Levels One/Two)"`

Link: `Nuclear Launch Codes (Levels One/Two) Blah Blah Blah`

Because the links do not always have the exact text I need to locate them like so: `/#{text}/`

Problem is that returns `"Nuclear Launch Codes (Levels One\/Two)"`

I though I would gsub the 1st parenthesis and everything after, but I need to keep it because I can have `Nuclear Launch Codes (Levels Four/Five)`

Is there anyway to modify the string to match the link while ignoring the rest of the link text?

Comment: Could you please edit to clarify your penultimate sentence?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, try:

```
/#{Regexp.escape(text)}/
```

Or equivalently, if you prefer:

```
Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(text))
```

This will automatically escape parentheses, slashes and so on in the `text` so they are not treated as special regexp characters.